# Hg postreview with private parent

Tags: version-control, mercurial, review-board

I have changesets like this:

```
A --> B --> C --> D
```

A is the public tip. D is the changeset I want to post for review. After reading: http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/users/tools/post-review/#distributed-version-control-systems, 
I expected this to work:

```
hg postreview tip --parent=-2
```

or

```
hg postreview tip --parent=C
```

But neither of the above seems to work. I get this error:

```
abort: The file was not found in the repository or parent revisionhas not been made public (207)
```

How can I make this happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like reviewboard want you to submit to review changesets **based on immutable history** only.

That means that `D` must be based on `A` if you want it to be submit-able without `B` or `C`.

This can be achieved using the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) bundled with Mercurial.

> hg rebase --dest A --source D